# Nothing is getting posted to my php script

Tags: php, http-post

I have a php script on my server and I am trying to post data from my ios app, but when I print the post variables I get a nil. Any idea why that is?

Swift

```
let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://xxxxxx.com/myFile.php")!
    let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
    let bodyData = "username=\(username.text)&password=\(password.text)"
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = bodyData.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request as URLRequest, queue: OperationQueue.main)
    {
        (response, data, error) in
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        //
        print("response \(responseString)")

    }
```

PHP

```
print_r($_POST); //prints: ([username] => xxxxxx [password] => yyyyyy)
json_encode($postVarUser);
json_encode($postVarPass);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it is the problem of echo($postUser);
just use json_encode($postUser);

Comment: Shoudn't `print_r` also print the post variables?

Comment: put all post variables into an array and encode them